# How can I add "set_read_timeout" from TcpStream to TlsStream?

Tags: rust, tcp, stream, settimeout, tls1.3

I'm new to Rust and I love the language more and more. I downloaded crate "native-tls" and it has the TlsStream element which replaces TcpStream but it doesn't have the "set_read_timeout" method. How do I access it by mixing libraries or something similar?

Something like this:

```
let mut stream = TlsStream::conn... 
TcpStream::stream.set_read_timeout(Duration::millis(5000));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. Set the timeout on the `TcpStream` before you give it to `TlsConnector::connect()`, or
2. Use [`TlsStream::get_mut()`](https://docs.rs/native-tls/latest/native_tls/struct.TlsStream.html#method.get_mut) to get a mutable reference to the underlying stream, which you can then invoke `set_read_timeout()` on:

   ```
   stream.get_mut().set_read_timeout(Duration::millis(5000));
   ```

Comment: As we say in our country "¡USTÉ ES UN MOSTRO PARCERO!", which translates that "YOU ARE A GENIUS MY FRIEND!".
Its works fine. THANK YOU VERY MUCH!